# How do I suck up the Mini Bosses?

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

I know that to earn some of the Energy Spheres in Kirby's Return to Dreamland, I need to suck up the mini boss in the level in order to use their specific Copy Ability. Problem is, I can never manage to do this - they disappear too quickly after I kill them.

Do I have to use Kirby's Super Inhale? How do I make sure I get the ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special.  You can inhale them normally then swallow them.

One thing to note however, when they are in the defeated state, you can still destroy them.  So once you deal the finishing blow, make sure you stop attacking them and go ahead and eat them.  Otherwise you might accidentally kill them off.

Comment: I suspect I was just killing them off completely. That explains a lot.